# Does SIGQUIT not have the effect of terminating a script in bash?

Tags: bash, signals

```
#!/bin/bash --

echo "$$"

LC_ALL=C sed 's/[!-~]/b/g' /tmp/bigfile > /tmp/outfile

echo end of script
```

If I send the `QUIT` signal using `Ctrl + \` I get this output:

```
# ./script.sh
6739
^\./script.sh: line 5:  6740 Quit                    LC_ALL=C sed 's/[!-~]/b/g' /tmp/bigfile > /tmp/outfile
end of script
```

This kills `sed` and causes a core dump as expected, but the script continues. Is this the expected behavior? This happens to me with `bash` and `ash` but not not `dash` or `ksh93`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `bash` ignores `SIGQUIT`. Quoting from its [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html#Signals) (emphasis mine):

> 3.7.6 Signals
>
> When Bash is interactive, in the absence of any traps, it ignores `SIGTERM` (so that `kill 0` does not kill an interactive shell), and `SIGINT` is caught and handled (so that the `wait` builtin is interruptible).
>   When Bash receives a `SIGINT`, it breaks out of any executing loops. **In all cases, Bash ignores `SIGQUIT`**.
>   If job control is in effect, Bash ignores `SIGTTIN`, `SIGTTOU`, and `SIGTSTP`.

This is non-standard behaviour, and most other shells don't do it.

---

If you don't find that convincing, you can have a look at its source code: `shell_initialize()` -> `initialize_signals(0)` -> `initialize_shell_signals()` -> [`set_signal_handler (SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN)`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/sig.c#n315) is non-conditionally called from `main()`.